# chrome.identity and YouTube v3 API?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was wondering if YouTube's v3 API and the OAuth2 support provided via chrome.identity played nicely together?

I can't seem to figure it out. Looking at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript they seem to take a CLIENT_ID and scope, much like I am passing into my manifest.json.

Is there anything I can do with my OAuth2 identity token? Or do I have to go completely through YouTube's authorization process?

**Update:** I can fetch data using YouTube's way now, but not using the way I wanted..

```
gapi.auth.authorize({  
    client_id: '{CLIENT ID}.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
    //  Set to false on first run to get pop-up interactivity
    immediate: true
}, function (authResult) {
    //console.log("Auth Result:", authResult);

    gapi.client.load('youtube', 'v3', function () {

        var request = gapi.client.youtube.channels.list({
            mine: true,
            part: 'contentDetails'
        });

        request.execute(function(response) {
            console.log("response:", response);
        });
    });  
});
```

My manifest.json has:

```
"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "{CLIENT ID}.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner"
    ]
  },
   "permissions": [
        "identity"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try 'gapi.auth.setToken': https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiauthsetToken. You first call chrome.identity.getAuthToken (declare the correct client id and scopes in your manifest.json first). In the callback use gapi.auth.setToken to set the OAuth 2 token.

Comment: Except it doesn't seem to like the auth token :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OAuth2 via the Google Javascript API is a separate process than the [chrome.identity](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity.html) API. The identity API uses the extension id to generate a unique access token.

**You have to choose one process over the other, their access tokens won't work with each other.**

I'm currently using the JavaScript OAuth2 with the Analytics service because the chrome.identity process requires submitting your extension to the Chrome web store. The downside to the JavaScript process is it requires me to generate the login flow for users.

Comment: I think I would like to use the chrome.identity process because it makes sense to keep all my permission requests in one location. Do you have any information on how to use the chrome.identity OAuth2 key to interface with the YouTube JavaScript API?

Comment: @SeanAnderson You most likely need to create a new client ID per the documentation, link in answer. Also check out [google groups about `chrome.identity`](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-apps/q4YuaWL6URk). Google groups is probably the better forum for the drawn out conversation this topic probably requires. If you start a post share the link, this is a topic I'll be dealing with soon.

Comment: Did you ever look into this more? I've re-approached it and found a solution, but it's a pretty obvious security issue. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900593/referer-security-when-requesting-a-simple-api-access-key

Comment: @SeanAnderson sorry I have not.